# How to write std::string to file?

Tags: c++

I want to write a `std::string` variable I am accepting from the user to a file. I tried using the `write()` method and it writes to the file. But when I open the file I see boxes instead of the string.

The string is only a variable length single word. Is `std::string` suitable for this or should I use a character array or something.

```
ofstream write;
std::string studentName, roll, studentPassword, filename;


public:

void studentRegister()
{
    cout<<"Enter roll number"<<endl;
    cin>>roll;
    cout<<"Enter your name"<<endl;
    cin>>studentName;
    cout<<"Enter password"<<endl;
    cin>>studentPassword;


    filename = roll + ".txt";
    write.open(filename.c_str(), ios::out | ios::binary);

    write.put(ch);
    write.seekp(3, ios::beg);

    write.write((char *)&studentPassword, sizeof(std::string));
    write.close();`
}
```

Comment: Please show your code. In general, _if_ correctly used, `std::string` is fine for this.

Comment: You need to save the 'payload' CONTENT of the string, not the string object as such (which typically contains just a length and a pointer to the actual content)

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You're currently writing the binary data in the `string`-object to your file. This binary data will probably only consist of a pointer to the actual data, and an integer representing the length of the string.

If you want to write to a text file, the best way to do this would probably be with an `ofstream`, an "out-file-stream". It behaves exactly like `std::cout`, but the output is written to a file.

The following example reads one string from stdin, and then writes this string to the file `output.txt`.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    std::ofstream out("output.txt");
    out << input;
    out.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `out.close()` isn't strictly neccessary here: the deconstructor of `ofstream` can handle this for us as soon as `out` goes out of scope.

For more information, see the C++-reference: http://cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/

Now if you need to write to a file in binary form, you should do this using the actual data in the string. The easiest way to acquire this data would be using `string::c_str()`. So you could use:

```
write.write(studentPassword.c_str(), studentPassword.size());
```

Comment: I had to add std::ios::binary for this to not have problems with newline characters

Comment: out.close() ? twice? bad answer

Comment: @caoanan it's to demonstrate the API. I also mention in the text of the body that it happens automatically when the variable goes out of scope. At any rate, `close()` is idempotent, so there's no harm in it being called multiple times.

Comment: In the last example, is it right to multiply `sizeof(char)`? Does it work even if the `sizeof(char)` is not 1? I'm asking this because `ofstream::write` accepts count(number of characters to write), not the number of bytes to write.

Comment: @starriet Actually, `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition. I removed `sizeof(char)` from the example since it's unnecessary and confusing.

Answer (score 33):

Assuming you're using a `std::ofstream` to write to file, the following snippet will write a `std::string` to file in human readable form:

```
std::ofstream file("filename");
std::string my_string = "Hello text in file\n";
file << my_string;
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the `ios::binary` from your modes in your ofstream and use `studentPassword.c_str()` instead of `(char *)&studentPassword` in your `write.write()`

Answer (score 0):

If you have fmt available:

```cpp
#include <fmt/os.h>
// ...
    fmt::output_file(filename).print("{}\0\0{}", ch, studentPassword);
// ...
```

But you are not really writing a password to a file, right?