# Find in C++ if a line from file contains a specific character

Tags: c++, filestream

I've read the lines from a textfile and i want to check if that line contains the $ sign.

That's what i got so far:

```
int main() {

    ifstream data_store;
    string line;
    data_store.open("c:\\test.txt");


    while (!data_store.eof())
    {

        getline(data_store, line);
        if (line.find("$"))
        cout << "1: " << line << endl;
    }


    data_store.close();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Furthermore how can i output them to a file ?

Comment: Are you having a problem with the finding portion?

Comment: And?  Is there a problem with it or are you just asking how to output to a file?

Comment: i dont work on c++ i dont know if its comparing the whole string to "$" or searching for it in line.find function

Comment: use `std::ofstream` to write to a file.

Comment: "Its not find the lines with $"  - huh? You have bugs, but this is simply not true.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath It will match any line that doesn't start with a $ (among other bugs).

Comment: @interjay: Yes. I explicitly said it has bugs. But what I said there was that OP wasn't telling the truth.

Answer (score 2):

To check if a line contains something using [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to need to check the returned value from `find` to make sure it is a valid return.  To do that we compare it against [`std::string::npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos) as that is what `find()` will return if it does not find anything.  This is the reason it finds every line as `std::string::npos` is still considered true when evaluated as a `bool`.  So refactoring your code you would have:

```
while (getline(data_store, line))
{
    if (line.find("$") != std::string::npos)
        cout << "1: " << line << endl;
}
```

I also changed the while loop as using `eof` is not how to control a while loop.  for more information on that see [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

As far as outputting the string to a file see: [How to write std::string to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388041/how-to-write-stdstring-to-file)

Answer (score 0):

It's a minor thing, but a variant of @NathanOliver's solution, is to use a `for` loop:

```
ifstream data_store("c:\\test.txt");

for ( string line; getline(data_store, line); ) {
  if ( line.find("$") != string::npos )
    cout << "1: " << line << endl;
}
// ...
```

The benefit here is that `line` is now local only to the loop, which is what it should be since that is the only place it is used.

Answer (score 0):

I did it yesterday forgot to update.

```
  #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>

using namespace std;

bool contains_number(const string &c);



int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    {
        string line1[100];
        ifstream myfile("D:/Users/Jarvan/Desktop/test.txt");

        int a = 0;

        if (!myfile)
        {
            cout << "Error opening output file" << endl;
            system("pause");
            return -1;
        }

        while (!myfile.eof())
        {
            getline(myfile, line1[a], '\n');

            if (contains_number(line1[a]))
            {
                count += 1;
                cout << line1[a] << "\n";
            }
            else cout << "\n";
        }
    }

    cout << count <<endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}



bool contains_number(const string &c)
{
    return (c.find_first_of("$") != string::npos);
}
```