# How to share file delete privilege when I opening a file by ifstream

Tags: c++, windows, file, winapi

I want to make the file that can be delete when it was opened by `ifstream`.

I know it is easy when using Windows API: `CreateFile`

```
CreateFile(...,FILE_SHARE_DELETE,...)
```

But when I test with opening a file by ifstream.

It can't be deleted when I opening it.

I didn't find any document about setting attribute such like `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` on `ifstream`.

How should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: You cannot in a portable way.

Comment: If I needed that I guess I'd look at ways to open an `ifstream` with an existing C `FILE` handle or file number, which in turn would correspond to an API level handle. Maybe

Comment: Some compilers (eg. `GCC`) offer the soon-to-be standard *filesystem* library as a `Technical Specification`. You can use: [std::experimental::filesystem::remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/fs/remove). Otherwise there is the same (or similar) library in `boost`.

Comment: @Galik That is unrelated to `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`

Comment: For Alf's suggestion, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475853/can-i-use-createfile-but-force-the-handle-into-a-stdofstream

Comment: Finally, I try to use Alf's suggestion and it works fine. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Visual Studio's version of `std::ifstream` has a non-standard constructor and a non-standard `open()` overload that both have an extra optional `_Prot` parameter for specifying "file protection/sharing flags" (see [`_fsopen()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f30b0db.aspx) for the list of available flags).  However, `delete` sharing is not one of supported flags.

There is an alternative, though.  Visual Studio's version of both `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream` have non-standard constructors that accept a `FILE*` for the file access.  You can wrap a `HANDLE` from `CreateFile()` into a `FILE*` using Microsoft's `_open_osfhandle()` and `_fdopen()` functions, for example (error handling removed for brevity):

[Can I use CreateFile, but force the handle into a std::ofstream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475853/)

```
HANDLE file_handle = CreateFile(...,FILE_SHARE_DELETE,...);
int file_descriptor = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)file_handle, _O_RDONLY);
FILE* file = _fdopen(file_descriptor, "r");
std::ifstream stream(file);
...
// Closes stream, file, file_descriptor, and file_handle.
stream.close();
```

If you need something more portable to non-Microsoft compilers, you will likely have to resort to writing a custom `std::basic_streambuf` class (or maybe derived from `std::filebuf`) to wrap your `HANDLE`, and then pass an object of that class to the `std::basic_istream` constructor directly.

Comment: This one is simple and easy than the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

File permissions differ by operating system:

- [Windows has](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Microsoft_Windows):

> Whole-file access-sharing for read, write, or delete

- *nix systems provide read, write, and execute permissions, but [as far as delete permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48580/73354), all that is needed is:

> write+execute permission on the parent directory. The permissions of the file itself are irrelevant

Since Windows is really the only system with delete access, and it already provides it's own accessor in the form of [`CreateFile` with `FILE_SHARE_DELETE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx#file_share_delete), there really isn't a motivation to standardize this functionality.

If this functionality is pivotal to your program you could implement this cross-platform function (note that depending upon file size this could be very expensive):

1. Open file for read and write with an [`fstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream); if this fails something else has a lock on the file and it would not be possible to open it for delete
2. [Slurp the file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/116220/2642059)
3. [`close`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/close) the file
4. [`remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove) the file; if this fails you do not have delete permissions on the file
5. Reopen the file for writing with an [`ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/basic_ostream)
6. ["Unslurp" the file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15388041/2642059) into the `ofstream`
7. Return the `ofstream`

As long as the returned `ofstream` is open the operating system is responsible for preventing changes to the permissions on the file or it's containing directories. So by virtue of the fact that you have already deleted the file you know that you can still delete the file upon closing the `ofstream`.