# how to export function's result to text file in C++?

Tags: c++

```
 int main()
{
shape a;           //make class

ostream out;
out.open("test.txt");      // make file
out<< a.draw();           // std::ostream << void        error
                          // draw() { cout<<"ddd"<<endl; }
out.close();
}
```

I want to wirte draw() in to file.
can you help me?

Comment: Use `#include<fstream>` library, which is just a child class of iostream but for files. You would do `ofstream ofs("test.txt")` to create a file stream.

Comment: `draw() { cout<<"ddd"<<endl; }` is this the code for the draw function. Because if it is draw will always write onto the console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write std::string to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388041/how-to-write-stdstring-to-file)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

1: Pass the stream to the function and write to that instead of `std::cout`

```
void draw(std::ostream& os) { os << "ddd\n"; }

int main()
{
    std::ofstream s("test.txt");
    draw(s);
}
```

2: Return the result instead of writing it

```
std::string draw() { return "ddd\n"; }

int main()
{
    std::ofstream s("test.txt");
    s << draw();
}
```