# Making Log File

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a log file using the code below, but It's not working and I'm unable to get the logs as the file is not created!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ofstream myfile;

int main () {

  myfile.open ("example.txt");
  if (!myfile.is_open())
  {
      cerr << "Failed to create Log" << endl;
  }
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";
  myfile.close();
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write std::string to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388041/how-to-write-stdstring-to-file)

Comment: Does it output _Failed to create Log_?

Comment: What happens when you run your program? Are you sure the file is created where you *think* it is? How do you run your program?

Comment: How do you run your program? How do you check that the file is not created?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp No! It's not! But I'm unable to locate the log file in my Current Directory!

Comment: @n.m. Using is_open() in code and trying to locate it in my current folder!!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm running it using Visual Studio in debug mode!

Comment: How do you know what your current directory is? Each program has its own current directory. You are probably looking at a wrong place.

Comment: Unless you have changed it in the settings, the default "current directory" is the project root directory IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it is working fine. compiled with g++ on ubuntu.

If your are using linux, try locating example.txt as may be the working directory is different. In windows, you can search for the file in your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get your code working, as it worked out of the box. Files created adhere to an odd structure, so you'll need to put your assembly version as a prefix either through a define or a variable.

You can find example.txt up a directory from Debug/Release, next to your .vcxproj file, and in the folder next to your .sln file.

Tinkeroonie is the name of my project, yours might be LoggerTest or something like that.

Highlighted is the folder you need.

[image]