# fread is reading garbage in file

Tags: c++, file-handling, fread

I am working on my assignment and faced a problem with fread() in C++. When I modify the name in my file it modifies it perfectly as I want but the problem occurs when I try to read the file after that, it reads the whole file but it does not stop after that it's running total 146 times whereas there are only 3 names.

My code:-

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct person{
    int id; 
    string fname; 

}s;

void write(){
    FILE *outfile;
    struct person input; 
    int num,ident;
    string sname[] = {"a","b","c"};

    outfile = fopen ("C:\\Users\\Amritesh\\Desktop\\students.txt","wb");

    if (outfile == NULL) 
    { 
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opend file\n"); 
        exit (1); 
    } 

    scanf("%d",&num);

    for(int i=0;i<num;i++){

        s.fname = sname[i];
        cin >> s.id;

        fwrite (&s, sizeof(s), 1, outfile);
    }
    fclose(outfile);
}

void read(){

    FILE *file1;
    int i=0;
    file1 = fopen ("C:\\Users\\Amritesh\\Desktop\\students.txt","r");

    while(fread(&s, sizeof(s), 1, file1) == 1) {    

        cout << "ID " << s.id << "  Name " <<s.fname << endl;
    }

    fclose (file1); 


} 

void modify(){
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen ("C:\\Users\\Amritesh\\Desktop\\students.txt","r+");

    while(fread(&s, sizeof(s), 1, file)) {

        if(s.fname == "a"){
            s.fname = "d";
            fseek(file,-sizeof(s),SEEK_CUR);
            fwrite (&s, sizeof(s), 1,file);
        }
    }

    fclose (file); 
}

int main(){
    write();
    modify();
    read();
}
```

**Edited code:-**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct person 
{ 
    int id; 
    string fname; 
}s,temp; 



void read() 
{ 
    int num;
    
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("C:\\Users\\Amritesh\\Desktop\\student.txt",ios::in);
    fin.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    

    //scanf("%d",&num);

    while(fin){

        cout << s.fname << s.id << endl;
    }

    fin.close();
}

void write(){

    int i=0;
    ofstream fout;

    fout.open("C:\\Users\\Amritesh\\Desktop\\student.txt");
    
    
    while(i!=2) {   
        cin >> s.id >> s.fname;
        fout << "ID " << s.id << "  Name " <<s.fname << endl;
        i++;
    }

    
    fout.close();
    
} 

void modify(){

    fstream mod;
    mod.open ("C:\\Users\\Amritesh\\Desktop\\student.txt");
    
    while(mod) {

        if(s.fname == "a"){
            s.fname = "d";
            mod.seekg(-sizeof(s),ios::cur);
            mod << s.fname;
        }
    }

    
    mod.close();
}

int main(){
    
    write();
    read();
    modify();
    
}
```

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: `string` is not a simple data type that you can read/write from a file like you are attempting.

Comment: Please take a look at [`size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size), and [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) or  [`data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data), those are the correct ways to get the size/length of an `std::string` and the pointer to it's data. Further more you might want to use `fstream` instead of c functions to read and write files in c++.

Comment: Mandatory reading: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Comment: Reading/writing class data from/to files is usually done by adding `operator>>` and `operator<<` overloads for the class. There are plenty of examples of how that's done here on SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write std::string to file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388041/how-to-write-stdstring-to-file)

Comment: I don't know what should do I now please answer what changes in code do I now.

Comment: @Amritesh I made an [example](https://godbolt.org/z/Ma75dE) using C++ streams and stream operators instead. It should get you started.

Comment: @TedLyngmo i have edited my code but it doesn't modifies string and also in terminal it's printing same string which i entered last for all inputs but in file it's printing correctly.

Comment: please help me with this.

Comment: @Amritesh Your `read()` in the edited code doesn't actually read anything. `while(fin)` will make the loop go on for as long as the `fin` stream doesn't have the `badbit` or `failbit` set. You only print the current values of the variables in `s` inside the loop. I guess that must go on indefinitely. In some places it looks like you're only guessing. `fin.seekg(0,ios::beg);` on a newly opened stream isn't necessary for example. Inside `write()` you actually _read_ values from `cin`: `cin >> s.id >> s.fname;` this looks very wrong. Did you look at my example?

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes, I looked at your example but it seems complex for me to understand . Can you make it easier please.

Comment: @Amritesh It's unclear what part of the example that is too complex. Does [this](https://godbolt.org/z/nj54EE) make it easier?

Comment: @TedLyngmo where you open the file and what is the use of those two operaters I am not able to understand.please guide me

Comment: @Amritesh `file` in my example is just a file in memory. (it's a `std::stringstream`) that I write to and read from just as any other `stream`. You can use `ofstream` to open a file for writing and `ifstream` to open a file for reading if you want it written to disk instead. That doesn't change what the `read` and `write` functions do. Like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/5nrbYa). (somewhat simplified and with some error checking)

Comment: If the example in my latest comment makes sense - [this](https://godbolt.org/z/YcjssE) is how it would look if I made `read` and `write` member functions in the `person` class:

Comment: @Amritesh I've now collected my suggestions in an answer instead. I hope you can find a version with a level of complexity that you feel comfortable with and that you can translate that into your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three ideas based on our discussion. I'll start with free functions for reading and writing a `person` object since it looks like you're at that stage right now. I'll move on to adding member functions in your `person` class and end with adding stream operators for convenience.

An example of free (non-member) `read` and `write` functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

struct person {
    int id; 
    std::string fname; 
};

std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os, const person& p) {
    os << p.id << ',' << p.fname << '\n'; // stream out the properties of a person
    return os; // look at the next example for an alternative doing the same thing
}

std::istream& read(std::istream& is, person& p) {
    // extract "id" and if it succeeds, check if the next char is a , char
    if(is >> p.id && is.peek() == ',') { 
        is.ignore();               // step over the , char
        std::getline(is, p.fname); // read the rest of the line into p.fname
    } else {
        // we didn't get id or the , char, so set the stream in a failed state
        is.setstate(is.failbit);       
    }
    return is;
}

int main() {
    // write to file
    {
        std::ofstream file("C:\\Users\\Amritesh\\Desktop\\student.txt");
        person test1{10, "Foo Bar"};
        person test2{20, "Apa Bepa"};
        write(file, test1);
        write(file, test2);
    }
    // read from file
    {
        std::ifstream file("C:\\Users\\Amritesh\\Desktop\\student.txt");
        person test;

        while(read(file, test)) {
            std::cout << test.fname << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

An example of making `read` and `write` member functions in `person`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

struct person {
    int id; 
    std::string fname;

    std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os) const {
        // this does the same thing as in the first example
        return os << id << ',' << fname << '\n';        
    }

    std::istream& read(std::istream& is) {
        if(is >> id && is.peek() == ',') {
            is.ignore(); // step over the , char
            std::getline(is, fname);
        } else {
            is.setstate(is.failbit); // we didn't get id or the , char
        }
        return is;
    }    
};

int main() {
    // write to file
    {
        std::ofstream file("C:\\Users\\Amritesh\\Desktop\\student.txt");
        person test1{10, "Foo Bar"};
        person test2{20, "Apa Bepa"};
        test1.write(file);
        test2.write(file);
    }
    // read from file
    {
        std::ifstream file("C:\\Users\\Amritesh\\Desktop\\student.txt");
        person test;

        while(test.read(file)) {
            std::cout << test.fname << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Member functions supported by stream operators:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

struct person {
    int id; 
    std::string fname;

    std::ostream& write(std::ostream& os) const {
        return os << id << ',' << fname << '\n';        
    }

    std::istream& read(std::istream& is) {
        if(is >> id && is.peek() == ',') {
            is.ignore(); // step over the , char
            std::getline(is, fname);
        } else {
            is.setstate(is.failbit); // we didn't get id or the , char
        }
        return is;
    }    
};

// stream operators calling member functions
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const person& p) { return p.write(os); }
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, person& p) { return p.read(is); }

int main() {
    // write to file
    {
        std::ofstream file("C:\\Users\\Amritesh\\Desktop\\student.txt");
        person test1{10, "Foo Bar"};
        person test2{20, "Apa Bepa"};
        file << test1 << test2;  // calling operator<< for each person object
    }
    // read from file
    {
        std::ifstream file("C:\\Users\\Amritesh\\Desktop\\student.txt");
        person test;

        while(file >> test) {    // extract one person at a time using operator>>
            std::cout << test.fname << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```